# Ubuntu Nexus 7 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nexus-7

I have Nexus 7. I updated from 13.04 to 14.04 but in the settings there is written that tablet is running 13.04 but in the terminal is 14.04. How do I find out which Ubuntu Nexus 7 is really running? You can see it in the pictures below.

[image: Terminal]
[image: Settings]

Comment: Personally, I would trust `lsb_release -a`

Answer (score 1):

`lsb_release -a` should be accurate

you can also check `cat /etc/issue.net`

You might want to check the details again to see if an upgrade was performed in between the posted pictures. My money is on you are running 14.04.3